# Arithmetic addition (+) is not working in ng-bind

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-bind

There is an object having

```
objData.pendingCount = '2',objData.refundCount = '1',objData.saleCount = 43;
```

I performed

```
<td ng-bind="(objData.pendingCount / objData.saleCount * 100).toFixed(2)"></td>
```

this is working fine but when I do

```
<td ng-bind="(objData.pendingCount +objData.refundCount)/ objData.saleCount * 100).toFixed(2)"></td>
```

Here + is not performing arithmetic opration rather it is concating. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Either `pendingCount` or `refundCount` is string. Try wrapping both in `Number()`

Comment: `refundCount`, I think. It's not in the first expression.

Comment: i tried <td ng-bind="(Number(objData.pendingCount) +Number(objData.refundCount))/ objData.saleCount * 100).toFixed(2)"></td> .. even I used parseInt() not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it using

```
<td ng-bind="(sum(objData.pendingCount,objData.refundCount)/objData.saleCount*100).toFixed(2)"></td>
```

and in the controller

```
$scope.sum = function (a, b) {
   return parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);
}
```

and it is working fine.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that these values come from a text box of some sort (via ng-model). If so, the easiest way to fix this would be to set a `type='number'` on them and angular will take care of the rest!

```
<input ng-model="objData.pendingCount" type="number" />
...
```

The alternative is to simply prefix + to force a number conversion, like so

```
<span ng-bind="((+objData.pendingCount + +objData.refundCount)/ objData.saleCount * 100).toFixed(2)"></span>
```

---

**Why you CANNOT use Number(...) to make a string a number in an Angular expression**

Using `Number` to convert the string to a number will not work directly because (from https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)

> Context: JavaScript expressions are evaluated against the global
>   window. In Angular, expressions are evaluated against a **scope** object.

So if you need to use `Number` you can do something like

```
$scope.Number = $window.Number;
```

in your controller before you use it in your expression. The same goes for other global window properties.

Comment: not working even I tried $scope.Math = $window.Math;

and performed Math.parseInt() not working

Comment: Its not working with the `(+objData.pendingCount + +objData.refundCount)/ objData.saleCount * 100).toFixed(2)`? or the $scope.Number one?

Comment: using `+objData....` does not work, but using `(1 * objData....)` does: http://jsfiddle.net/5qnvnebg/

Comment: That is strange (I was trying with a textbox bound to the model values - it works there). Interestingly `--objData.pendingCount + --objData.refundCount` works

Comment: @potatopeelings, it may work in actual JavaScript, but apparently not in the Angular expression parser.

Comment: @JackA : the -- one actually works in OPs fiddle. The + actually works if you don't initialize but instead bind it to a textbox.

Comment: @SunilGarg - Number seems to work too if you do the $scope.Number thing - http://jsfiddle.net/tdouesc5/

Comment: --objData.pendingCount + --objData.refundCount   this is working. thanks @potatopeelings

Answer (score 2):

corrects your expression:

```
<td ng-bind="(objData.pendingCount +objData.refundCount)/ (objData.saleCount * 100).toFixed(2)"></td>
```

is missing an open parentheses

Comment: or where it should be

Comment: uses <td ng-bind="(parseFloat(objData.pendingCount) +parseFloat(objData.refundCount))/ (objData.saleCount * 100).toFixed(2)"></td>

Comment: the point is: It should be better if your object property is directly a float or integer... But if you're receiving a string from backend, use parseFloat()

Comment: Just like to point that it's not a good practice to do the calculation like this.
Use the controller to perform the calculation and then fetch the calculated value in the view.

Comment: this is not good practice but there is ng-repeat so for this i have to perform looping . so to avoid loop i am trying it on view (html)

Comment: Here's the plunker of what I mean
http://plnkr.co/edit/9eQeczu94WzQzY2MP6Bx?p=preview

Edit: repeat compatible

Comment: Yes @AminMohamedAjani, but the original object, from the issue above, contains string on values: objData.pendingCount = '2',objData.refundCount = '1'... But I agree with your code.

Comment: I added +$scope.blahblah to enforce it into a number. I almost forgot about that little hack until potatoepeelings mentioned it in his answer lol

Comment: excellent... I did not know this trick before... this and double exclamation (!!) are the top tricks for 2015, for me

Comment: "bang, bang you're boolean"